# API response failed with illegal string offset and contains unknown characters

Tags: php, wechat

I am using [overtrue/wechat](https://github.com/overtrue/wechat) to develop a [wechat](http://www.wechat.com/en/) project.

When developing with [overtrue/wechat batchget API](https://github.com/overtrue/wechat/wiki/%E7%94%A8%E6%88%B7%E4%B8%8E%E7%94%A8%E6%88%B7%E7%BB%84%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86),

mycode:

```
$usersInfo = array();
$usersInfo = $userService->batchGet($usingOpenids);
```

it returns error:

ErrorException in [User.php line 103](https://github.com/overtrue/wechat/blob/2.1/src/Wechat/User.php#L103):

```
Illegal string offset 'user_info_list'.
```

I checked some responses, then I found some unknown characters like pictures below (open with sublime). However Other responses are correct.

[image][image]

---

Below is wechat batchGet API, overtrue/wechat's batchget function is aiming to do things below:

HTTP POST: 
    https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/user/info/batchget?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

POST data:

```
{
    "user_list": [
        {
            "openid": "otvxTs4dckWG7imySrJd6jSi0CWE", 
            "lang": "zh-CN"
        }, 
        {
            "openid": "otvxTs_JZ6SEiP0imdhpi50fuSZg", 
            "lang": "zh-CN"
        }
    ]
}
```

Response Data:

```
{
   "user_info_list": [
       {
           "subscribe": 1, 
           "openid": "otvxTs4dckWG7imySrJd6jSi0CWE", 
           "nickname": "iWithery", 
           "sex": 1, 
           "language": "zh_CN", 
           "city": "Jieyang", 
           "province": "Guangdong", 
           "country": "China", 
           "headimgurl": "http://wx.qlogo.cn/mmopen/xbIQx1GRqdvyqkMMhEaGOX802l1CyqMJNgUzKP8MeAeHFicRDSnZH7FY4XB7p8XHXIf6uJA2SCunTPicGKezDC4saKISzRj3nz/0", 
           "subscribe_time": 1434093047, 
           "unionid": "oR5GjjgEhCMJFyzaVZdrxZ2zRRF4", 
           "remark": "", 
           "groupid": 0
       }, 
       {
           "subscribe": 0, 
           "openid": "otvxTs_JZ6SEiP0imdhpi50fuSZg", 
           "unionid": "oR5GjjjrbqBZbrnPwwmSxFukE41U", 
       }
   ]
}
```

---

So what can I do to avoid this error?
I guess maybe the problem is here [Http.php line 116](https://github.com/overtrue/wechat/blob/2.1/src/Wechat/Http.php#L116). Maybe I can transfer format here?
But I don't know how.

> $contents = json_decode($response['data'], true);

---

PS: I'm sorry about that some docs are Chinese...

Comment: I think you are mixing up unicode formats

Comment: @Grantly So what should I do?

Comment: Show us where you declare your external API function (and library settings).  It could be a problem with your declaration, or with the type of string you are assigning the value to, or you may have to convert to a different unicode set.  Can you find out exactly the format of unicode that it outputs?

Comment: @Grantly I decaled usersInfo as array. I install overtrue/wechat with composer, then I use batchGet() function to get users' info. And it returns illegal string offset. This function will lead to here https://github.com/overtrue/wechat/blob/2.1/src/Wechat/User.php#L90.

Comment: I don't know php, but does the array() give you a unicode string? Can you force it to a different unicode format? (ie When you declare it?)?

Comment: Also show us the line that the error occurs on

Comment: That error message means you're trying to use a string as an associative array. So you're probably using the wrong variable name. WHat's on line 93?

Comment: @Grantly Now I use json_encode to format it again and it works. thanks~

Comment: @Barmar I didn't use wrong variable name. But you give me an inspiration, I reuse json_encode to format it and it works. Thanks~

Comment: @GoneWithSin Thats great. Perhaps add an Answer to this Question so that everyone can enjoy your solution :)  Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: @Grantly I have added my answer. thanks for answering the question~

Answer (score 1):

As comments says this error means I am using a string as an array.
So I add json_decode again to format response in [User.php](https://github.com/overtrue/wechat/blob/2.1/src/Wechat/User.php#L103).

```
    if(!is_array($response))
    {
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
    }
```

However, there's still something confusing me. Because in [Http.php](https://github.com/overtrue/wechat/blob/2.1/src/Wechat/Http.php#L116), it has already used json_decode function. Now I use json_decode in [User.php](https://github.com/overtrue/wechat/blob/2.1/src/Wechat/User.php#L103) again.
So maybe there's a better way or other problems. However, this is one way to solve it. Thanks for all answering the question~